# Advice on Transferring data from Azure SQL server database to Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-transfer

I am trying to transfer the reporting database from the Azure SQL server to Snowflake.

Would you please give me some tips and guide me on the best tools to automate this process?

Our Azure database updated every 1 hour, so I need to transfer the data and update it accordingly in Snowflake.

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 tools that have a free tier offering and support this use case:

Matillion Data Loader: https://www.matillion.com/products/data-loader/

StitchData: https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/microsoft-azure/snowflake/

Answer (score 0):

You can use data integration  tools from partener connect  marketplace such as Informatica , Fivetran or Qlick ; these tools have capability to load full as well as incremental data from various source systems such as SQL Server, Oracle , MySql.With task automation feature of these tool you can have change  data load near real time too and automatically..